# ui and cpp files are out of sync

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5

Everything was fine until I decided to add another combobox (which I did not rename and is indeed called comboBox) into my .ui when I realized that ui->comboBox was not recognized. All my other widgets etc that I added awhile ago still work though. When I debug I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVs8X.png but i know for a fact that I created it. Usually bugs like these I could just close my Qt and start it up again and all would be well but not this time. Does anyone know how to possibly fix this issue? I'm using Qt5.1.0.

I noticed this problem after I built Qt statically. Could that be the issue?

Example:
detail.ui
[image: http://puu.sh/3yl6F.png]

trying to access the button in detail.cpp
[image]

As you can see, i can still access all of the previous widgets etc before I made Qt Statically. But now, when I make a new pushbutton, cpp file does not recognize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to run Qt5.1.0 for Desktop (MinGW4.8 32bit) prompt. cd `C:\path\to\project.pro` and then type `mingw32-make clean`

Comment: _run qmake_ from build menu should have done the trick, if you haven't tried that yet, try it next time you have similar issues.

Comment: @Zlatomir I tried that prior to `ming..clean` and it didn't work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a copy of the auto generated "ui_xyz" file in my working directory(source files) so the compiler wasn't referring to new one in the build directory.